# Docker on Ubuntu Server fails to deploy on Azure

Tags: ubuntu, docker, azure

I am following [these directions](http://www.mikelanzetta.com/tensorflow-on-azure-using-docker.html) to run TensorFlow on Docker and Azure. I go to `portal.azure.com`, click "Create a Resource", then search for and click on "Docker for Ubuntu Server", and click "Create" (with machine size "Standard A1").

The deployment does not finish and when I click "Deployment in progress", I get this alert:

> The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'. Click here for details

and with details:

> The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state
>   'Failed'. (Code: ResourceDeploymentFailure)
>
> - The virtual machine 'hostname' provisioning state is 'Failed', because
>     extension 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions.DockerExtension' is in state
>     'Ready'. (Code: VirtualMachineProvisioningFailed)

Following [this thread](http://htykuut.blogspot.com/2018/12/azure-docker-vm-error.html), I found that the virtual machine was created, found its IP address, and SSH'd into it and find the logs:

```
$ ls -la /var/log/
total 420
drwxrwxr-x  9 root   syslog   4096 Jan  9 15:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root     4096 Jun 27  2016 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      357 Jan  9 15:22 alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Jun 28  2016 apt
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm     13368 Jan  9 20:09 auth.log
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root     4096 Jan  9 15:21 azure
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     5179 Jan  9 15:22 azure-docker-extension-enable.log
-rw-------  1 root   utmp     1536 Jan  9 19:55 btmp
-rw-r--r--  1 syslog adm     97337 Jan  9 15:20 cloud-init.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     5324 Jan  9 15:20 cloud-init-output.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Apr 26  2016 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    42140 Jan  9 15:22 dpkg.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Jun 27  2016 fsck
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm     55580 Jan  9 15:22 kern.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp   292292 Jan  9 20:09 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 May 30  2016 lxd
drwxr-x---  2 root   adm      4096 May 20  2016 samba
-rw-r-----  1 syslog adm    122943 Jan  9 20:09 syslog
drwxr-x---  2 root   adm      4096 Feb 21  2016 unattended-upgrades
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     3680 Jan  9 15:21 waagent.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 root   utmp     3456 Jan  9 20:09 wtmp
```

The error seems in line with `azure-docker-extension-enable.log`, which ends with

```
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:27 no restart needed. issuing only a start command.
[executil] 2019/01/09 21:17:27 +++ invoke: systemctl [start docker]
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[executil] 2019/01/09 21:17:27 --- invoke end
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 -- restart docker
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 ++ login docker registry
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 registry login not specificied
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 -- login docker registry
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 ++ compose up
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 docker-compose config not specified, noop
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 -- compose up
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 - completed: 'enable'
[DockerExtension] 2019/01/09 21:17:30 Cleaned up .seqnum file.
```

So I ran this command:

```
$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-01-09 15:22:50 UTC; 4h 50min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 10048 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H=fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 10048 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 09 15:22:50 hostname systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 09 15:22:50 hostname systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jan 09 15:22:50 hostname systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 09 15:22:50 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

and this other command:

```
$ journalctl -xe
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jan 09 20:09:58 hostname systemd[10602]: Reached target Basic System.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jan 09 20:09:58 hostname systemd[10602]: Reached target Default.
-- Subject: Unit UNIT has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jan 09 20:09:58 hostname systemd[10602]: Startup finished in 35ms.
-- Subject: System start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- All system services necessary queued for starting at boot have been
-- successfully started. Note that this does not mean that the machine is
-- now idle as services might still be busy with completing start-up.
-- 
-- Kernel start-up required KERNEL_USEC microseconds.
-- 
-- Initial RAM disk start-up required INITRD_USEC microseconds.
--
```

Any suggestions to deploy Docker on Ubuntu and Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be an error on the Microsoft side. I tried it again today (one week later) and the deployment has no issues.